# Conjugate convolution

Tags: operator-theory, convolution

I have 
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\|y - A*x\|_2^2,
$$
where x is matrix of size $512 \times 512$ and A is kernel of shape $5 \times 5$ for example. Then I want to find derivative of $f$ by x:

Rewrite this in operator form as:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\|y - \mathcal{A}x\|_2^2,
$$
here $\mathcal{A}$ is convolution operator, so derivative is:
$$
\nabla f = - \mathcal{A}^*(y - \mathcal{A}x)
$$

but what is $\mathcal{A}^*$?

Comment: what norm is $\|{\cdot}\|$?

Comment: frobenius norm as $||x||^2 = \sum\limits_{i,j} x_{i,j}^2$